# tkintertable data how to update

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tkintertable

I'm using tkintertable git cloned from github. Basically using the same example as [the other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34094475/how-can-i-have-the-tkintertable-tables-columns-sorted-the-way-they-are-in-the-d).

How do you add a raw of data into the table after the tkinter has been in its mainloop? How do you update data in the current table?

In the code below, I added a callback and use a tkinter `after()` to call. In the callback it tries to add a row to the data model. I also tried directly adding a key/value pair to the `data` object. Neither of them worked.

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkintertable.Tables import TableCanvas
from tkintertable.TableModels import TableModel
master=Tk()
tframe = Frame(master)
tframe.pack(fill='both')
data={'1': {'Klasa':'6A', 'E Hene': 1, 'E Marte': 2,'E Merkurre':3,'E Enjte':4,'E Premte':5},
      '2': {'Klasa':'', 'E Hene': 1, 'E Marte': 2,'E Merkurre':3,'E Enjte':4,'E Premte':5}}
model = TableModel()
table = TableCanvas(tframe,model=model)
table.createTableFrame()
model = table.model
model.importDict(data) #can import from a dictionary to populate model

def update_data(event=None):
    global data
    global model
    nk = "3"
    print "update_data \n"
    model.addRow(key=nk,
                 Klasa="333")
master.after(5000, update_data)

master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [documentation](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/tkintertable/wiki/Usage)

> ## Update the table
>
> This needs to be called to update the display after programmatically
> changing the table contents:
>
> ```
> table.redraw()
> ```

So you need

```
model.addRow(key=nk, Klasa="333")
table.redraw()
```

And it works on my computer.

Comment: awesome! it also works with [1] modify data, [2] `model.importDict()`, [3] `table.redraw()`.